# ASP compatibility mode error while creating Excel file using CreateObject("XLSpeedGen.ASP")

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vb.net, com

When I am trying to create an Excel file using below code in my local machine (64-bit machine), I am getting below error.

```
<%@ Page ASPCompat="True" language="vb" %>
<%
  Dim XLS             ' Excel SpeedGen Object
  XLS = Server.CreateObject("XLSpeedGen.ASP")  <--- I am getting error in this line
  XLS.AddVariable("Name", strName)
  XLS.Generate(SrcBook, "", False)
%>
```

**Exception Details:**

> System.Web.HttpException: An error was encountered while calling
>   OnStartPage in ASP compatibility mode.

**Stack Trace:**

> [HttpException (0x80004005): An error was encountered while calling
>   OnStartPage in ASP compatibility mode.]
>   System.Web.Util.AspCompatApplicationStep.OnPageStart(Object component)
>   +3028336    System.Web.HttpServerUtility.CreateObject(String progID) +142

I have registered "XLSpeedGenASP.dll" using below code in my local machine.

```
regsvr32 "E:\XLSpeedGen\XLSpeedGenASP.dll"
```

Still I am getting the same error. How to resolve the above mentioned issue?

Comment: Does that component do something you cannot do with a library from this century? Even if you get it working I wouldn't trust it for stability or security. There are many options for working with Excel and some are free.

Comment: @Crowcoder, Thank you for your comments. This project has been created by someone way back 2008 or before and right now I am doing support for this project. I need to debug the code locally now.

Comment: Yeah, its a bummer. Of course I have no idea what it would take to refactor that component out of your code base in favor of a new library but if it is at all practical hopefully you/your team/your manager would consider it. Excel on the server is notorious for memory leaks which is why we work with the XML of excel files these days instead of Excel Application objects.

Comment: @Crowcoder, You are telling that even creating Excel file using below Excel Applications objects "Dim xl As New Excel.Application" will also leak memory?. Do you know any open source XML libraries for generating Excel files with features like Pivot table and row merging?

Comment: I don't know what advance features it has but [ClosedXML](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML) is easy to use. Also look at EPPlus. At the very least you can use the Open XML SDK to do anything you want but it is not the most intuitive library.

Comment: @RGS, you summoned me here in the linked question but now it looks like you decided to do the right thing and get rid of a legacy component. Did that not work out well?

Comment: @noseratio, I need to debug the code locally. If you have any ideas to resolve the above issue, please provide an answer.

Comment: Have you tried a standalone vbs script to create this object outside asp.net? You can run it via cscript.exe.

Comment: @noseratio, I will check with cscript.exe. The same solution is running without any issues in production environment. Could you please help me to fix the issue to run locally? Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: The best things I can suggest to troubleshoot the issue with your local environment is to study event viewer logs, check the file system permission for that DLL location, particularly for the system account your ASP.NET app runs under. You can also use some heavy weapon like ProcMon from Sysinternals to try to get a more specific error details.

Comment: @noseratio, I have installed ProcMon in my system. But ProcMon tool is not logging the error details whenever I got the error mentioned in the question. I have also verified event viewer logs. There is no specific information available for this error. Also I have checked the file system permission for that DLL. Still I am not able to clear this issue.

Comment: So did it work in a standalone VBS script under `cscript`? Procmon is really powerful and should give you more details on what led to 0x80004005. Search YouTube for videos on advanced use of Procmon. Sorry, I'm not sure how else I can help you.

Comment: @noseratio, I will check the steps mentioned in the comment. Thank you for your continuous inputs.